# AS3 Sound, jump forward?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am playing a looping sound in as3, is there a way to jump to a specific part of teh sound, say 20 seconds in during playback when a user presses a btn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already created your Sound and SoundChannel objects.

```
private var mySound:Sound;
private var mySoundChannel:SoundChannel;

function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var pos:Number = 0;
    if ( mySoundChannel ) {
        pos = mySoundChannel.position;
        mySoundChannel.stop();
    }
    //jump ahead 20 seconds, the play accepts time in ms
    mySoundChannel = mySound.play(pos + (20 * 1000));
}
```